# GWR and OLS regression models

Tags: arcmap

I'm somewhat confused about regression models. I decided to create a GWR model for a project using 35 polygons of health data. However I find now that my model has flaws and I cannot create a GWR model probably because the dataset is too small.

When creating a OLS are we meant to remove all variables that are related? if I'm modelling obesity, I would think that income, exercise are factors that relate to it so what purpose does the OLS model serve? I created a model after removing auto correlated variables but I'm kind of confused as to what its meant to be showing.

Comment: This might help answer your question.

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27245/regression-model-and-spatial-autocorrelation

Answer (score 1):

This might help answer your question.

[Regression Model and Spatial Autocorrelation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27245/regression-model-and-spatial-autocorrelation)

It gives you the understanding of how the OLS and GWR are statistically different.